# floating side menu, make it stop at bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

### [example page](http://jsbin.com/ujeva)

I have a floating menu that i've built to the left side (green), 
and i've made it start moving after 200 pixels. and now i need to to stop
and not go over the footer (blue) area.
any ideas how to make my JS better?

this thing is, I cannot check this on the scroll event, because of the animation
going on after i scroll, so it needs to be done someway else.

so how to make the animation stop at the end just before the footer?

Comment: I think you have aasked this question before. Try to edit the previous one rather than posting a new one if both are the same.

Comment: sorry, didn't know i can edit :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've resolved the issue perfectly (hope so)

with the help of you guys, and released 

a jQuery plugin for floating sticky boxes:

[**http://plugins.jquery.com/project/stickyfloat**](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/stickyfloat)

Answer (score 1):

```
$.fn.menuFloater = function(options) {
    var opts = $.extend({ startFrom: 0, offsetY: 0, attach: '', duration: 50 }, options);
    // opts.offsetY
    var $obj = this;
    $obj.css({ position: 'absolute' /*, opacity: opts.opacity */ });


    /* get the bottom position of the parent element */
    var parentBottomPoint = $obj.parent().offset().top + $obj.parent().height() ; 
    var topMax = $obj.parent().height() - $obj.innerHeight() + parseInt($obj.parent().css('padding-top')); //get the maximum scrollTop value
    if ( topMax < 0 ) {
        topMax = 0;
    }

    console.log(topMax);

    $(window).scroll(function () { 
        $obj.stop(); // stop all calculations on scroll event
        //  console.log($(document).scrollTop() + " : " + $obj.offset().top);

        /* get to bottom position of the floating element */
        var isAnimated = true;
        var objTop= $obj.offset().top;
        var objBottomPoint = objTop + $obj.outerHeight();

        if ( ( $(document).scrollTop() > opts.startFrom || (objTop - $(document).scrollTop()) > opts.startFrom ) && ( $obj.outerHeight() < $(window).height() ) ){
            var adjust;
            ( $(document).scrollTop() < opts.startFrom ) ? adjust = opts.offsetY : adjust = -opts.startFrom + opts.offsetY;
            // and changed here to take acount the maximum scroll top value
            var newpos = ($(document).scrollTop() + adjust );
            if ( newpos > topMax ) {
                newpos = topMax;
            }
            $obj.animate({ top: newpos }, opts.duration, function(){ isAnimated = false } );
        }
        else {
            $obj.stop();
        }
    });

};
```

Comment: +1 confirmed that this works. There are some superfluous things in there though. For instance, the 'isAnimated' value is irrelevant as the animation is being stopped regardless.

Comment: Well all I did was add the things that were needed to prevent the menu going lower that it had to, I didn't remove any of the original code, leaving removal of the useless things as an exercise to the original author :)

Comment: yes, excellent! very good, thanks! I will clean the code now, i know there are irrelevant things in it.

thank. why do you check - if( topMax < 0 )  ?

anyway i don't think its necessary because i disabled animation if
the window size is smaller than the menu, because the user must see it all.

Comment: Oh you know - just in case :)

Answer (score 0):

In the `$(window).scroll` function have you checked whether the bottom position of the floating div is less than or equal to the top position of the footer element.

Comment: can't do that. when i scroll and the $(window).scroll is triggered, the animation kicks in. and i don't know where it gonna take the menu to after it starts.